# How many ways are there to arrange 4 letters from the word PROGRAM?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question doesn't mention unique words or repetition. How to know whether it is permutation or combination ?

Is it correct to say there are 7 letters in the word PROGRAM and R occurs 2 times,
hence from 6 different letters there are 6C4 x 4C4 ways of arranging 4 letters from the word PROGRAM ?

Comment: I think it means when you show the result to other people, how many results they will see. And it's a permutation problem.

Comment: Generally, when you continuously choose objects out of the same source, its permutations are considered.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the question is how many $4$ letter words can be formed from the letters in the word PROGRAM. All such words can be categorized as either containing no R's, containing $1$ R or containing $2$ R's.

Containing no R's : In how many ways can you select $4$ letters from P, O, G, A, M and arrange $4$ different letters?

Containing $1$ R : In how many ways can you select $3$ letters from P, O, G, A, M and arrange $4$ different letters?

Containing $2$ R's : In how many ways can you select $2$ letters from P, O, G, A, M and arrange $4$ letters out of which $2$ are the same?